# Remove files with a certain hashsum

Tags: linux

Whats the ideal command to remove files with a certain hashsum on a standard linux system (using md5sum for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ONE ideal command, however there is a combination of `find`, `md5sum`, `xargs`, `grep`, `awk` and `rm` commands that will do the job when properly piped together in a command line.

```
 find dirx -type f -print | xargs md5sum | grep '^value ' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm
```

Comment: What I obviously mean is the best "combination of commands" to do that job. Might want to give an example?

Comment: I don't understand, I gave you the whole thing.

Comment: `-print0` and `-0` are of little use if you continue with plain awk and xargs.

Comment: ok....I'll remove them....